# Poisson process doubt (cars question)

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

Cars arrive according to a Poisson process with a rate of 12 per hour.
(1) What is the probability that the third car that arrives after 8 AM arrives within 10 minutes of the first car that arrives after 8 AM?

What I tried: Should we calculate the probability of three or more cars in 10 minutes?

(2) A car has a 1/4 chance of being Japanese. What is the probability that exactly 5 Japanese and 10 non-Japanese cars arrive between 8 and 9 AM?

Is this a mix of binomial and poisson?

Comment: For the first problem it would be useful to make a sketch. Draw three cars in various ways. How would you reformulate that third car arriving within 10 minutes after the first car?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings We don't really care about the first car's arrival time. So should we simply calculate the probability of 2 cars arriving in 10 minutes?

Comment: Your formulation of the second problem is right although you could also reformulate it in terms of two independent Poisson problems. You could try to show that they are equivalent.

Comment: Say the first three cars after 8 am arrive 8:40, 8:42, 8:49 then did "the third car that arrives after 8 AM arrive within 10 minutes of the first car that arrives after 8 AM?"

Comment: @MartijnWeterings yes, I suppose so.